# Did Prophet Muhammad call for Jihad to kill non Muslims or force them to convert?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, non-muslim, jihad

I'm really doubtful about this question. I always thought Islam was a beautiful and peaceful religion. But what ISIS and al Qaeda are doing these days makes me think otherwise. All the Jihad in the Hadith - did Mohammed really wage Jihad to kill non Muslims or convert them?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.lettertobaghdadi.com/ might help put your mind at ease.  The question might even be answered in the jihad section.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38824/17702) for references in Islamic legal discourse that encourage regular aggressive jihad against peaceful Non-Muslims. Also, consider how fast the Islamic empire expanded - it reached from Spain to China within 120 years after Muhammad's death - and the history of more or less continuous jihad after that until the decline of the caliphate.

Comment: Since the question in the title is ambiguously worded, and literally *none* of the existing answers seem to be answering it anyway, I am closing this as unclear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Islam is not a violent religion. What these terrorists are doing are not correct and have complete misunderstood the Quran.

God Almighty Says:

> ”Whoever kills an innocent human being, it shall be as if has killed all mankind, and Whoever saves the life of one, it shall be as if he had saved the life of mankind” [Quran 5:32]

And you will not find in any religion that loves war. Every religion wants and orders peace.

God Says:

> ”Those who believe fight in the cause of God...”Quran (4:76)

In here it meant to those who attack Muslims, if for example, a group of disbelievers attack Muslims, then Muslims would attack back as a defense only. Right?

But those who do evil, God will caste them(ISIS and other terrorists and those who reject the truth and those who do bad) in Fire on the Day of Judgment unless one of them repented before death.

The job of Muhammad was to be a prophet and messenger to deliver God’s messages, and he did not forced anyone to convert to Islam, he just delivered and that’s it, those who convert to Islam is good for them and they did themselves because they feel that Islam is good and the most easiest religion, and because they can feel that every single word from Quran is indeed 100% true.

Prophet Muhammad said:

> “Whoever kills an innocent non-Muslim will not even smell the fragrance of Paradise.” [Bukhārī]

How could this statement possibly be compatible with the ridiculous idea that Islam forces itself on others? Instead, it makes it clear that no non-Muslim is allowed to be harmed because of what they believe. So you see? They misunderstood it, and it is everyone’s right and that is only when a county is an Islamic state. Also God Almighty Says:

> And had your Lord willed, those on earth would have believed – all of them entirely. Then, [O Muhammad], would you compel the people in order that they become believers?

This means if God wishes everyone to become a believer, to accept Islam, then today in 2018 Earth will full of true believers and there was no need for anyone to force anyone to convert to Islam, for example, my Muslim father delivered the message of Islam, and he did not forced me but next day I have converted to Islam because I feel and know that it is true, without being forced.

God Says:

> ”O my people have you considered: if I should be upon clear evidence from my Lord while He has given me mercy from Himself but it has been made unapparent to you, should we force it upon you while you are averse to it?” [Surah Hud 11:28]

God told prophet Muhammad to turn away peacefully from disbelievers, reminding him  they will come to know one day that they have rejected the truth:

> ”So turn away from them and say ‘Peace,’ for they shall come to know” (43.89).

**CONCLUSION:** Muhammad fought only to recover his homeland from stubborn polytheists, and he things by God’s will and he does only what God orders him to do. And he only delivered the message of God and those who declared war on him are the disbelievers and they did with their own hands, that’s why many people believe that Islam force others to convert to Islam.

Answer (score -2):

In the Shia school of thought, jihad for the mere reason of conquest is not allowed. The followers of the Holy Household of the Prophet (Ahl-ul-Bayt) criticise the way Islam was spread by force after the death of the Prophet.

Ayatollah Sayyid Fadhel [Milani](http://almilani.com/English), a contemporary Shia scholar based in  London, in his book "Frequently Asked Questions on Islam",(p.84) listed the following essential guidelines regarding jihad:

> - Must be in defence in the way of Allah, not merely for conquest.
>
>   - Must be to restore peace and freedom of worship.
>   - The supervision, approval and permission of the spiritual leader, or the supreme jurist of the community is required.
>   - Should only be fought until the enemy lays down arms.
>   - No one is allowed to harm women, children, the elderly and sick. No one is allowed to damage the environment and sources of life such as
>       crops, water supplies and livestock.

In an answer to a question about the necessity of war  he states:

> Jihad is not waged to force people to accept Islam. Islam does not
>   force people to accept a new creed; it was revealed to enlighten them
>   and remove the yoke of ignorance.

Comment: Does this mean Shia clerics have a consensus that conquest is forbidden? On another answer you commented he can't cite one Shia conference to establish that conquest is allowed; seems reasonable to hold yourself to the same standard with regard to establishing that it is haram.

Comment: She is unaware of website called al-islam.org and their acceptance of conquest by jihad

Comment: Al-Islam.org is a  very valuable digital library of Shia books, articles, conference papers etc. which I often use for referencing. But not every statement in a book or article found on al-Islam.org represents the school of Ahl-ul-Bayt correctly. Sometimes  authors state their own opinion without verification.

Answer (score -4):

Muslims are peaceful only with those who are peaceful with them.

Prophet indeed called for Jihad as per instructions of Quran 9:5 and Quran 9:29.

To understand the concept of jihad, one needs to understand the purpose of Allah sending the prophets.

Allah sent prophets with book and balance (sword) to spread the message of tawheed. Jihad to spread Islam is **only after failure of peaceful invites to non muslim rulers**.

Prophet solomon initially sent a message to queen balqis and later warned of impending Jihad on her kingdom.

> "Go back to them. We verily shall come to them with hosts that they cannot resist, and we shall drive them out from there in disgrace, and they will be abased." (An-Naml 27:37)

Conquest by Jihad is agreed upon by 3 schools, Shia, Deobandi(hanafi) and salafi.

- Shia School

> Jihad with unbelievers so that they may abandon their false beliefs and incline towards Islam. This type of jihad is referred to as al‑jihad al‑ 'ibtidai (a case when fighting is initiated by Muslims) and has its own particular conditions and involves elaborate discussion.

Reference: https://www.al-islam.org/al-tawhid/vol1-n3/defence-and-jihad-quran-ahmad-jannati/defence-and-jihad-quran

- Hanafi/deobandi school

> Thus one of the primary responsibilities of the Muslim ruler is to spread Islam throughout the world, thus saving people from eternal damnation.
>
> Thus what is meant by the passage in Tafsir Uthmani, is that if a country doesn't allow the propagation of Islam to its inhabitants in a suitable manner or creates hindrances to this, then the Muslim ruler would be justifying in waging Jihad against this country, so that the message of Islam can reach its inhabitants, thus saving them from the Fire of Jahannum. If the Kuffaar allow us to spread Islam peacefully, then we would not wage Jihad against them.

Reference : http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/12128.html

- Salafi School.

> Undoubtedly taking the initiative in fighting has a great effect in spreading Islam and bringing people into the religion of Allaah in crowds. Hence the hearts of the enemies of Islam are  filled with fear of jihad.

Reference: https://islamqa.info/en/43087

Additionally we have narrations in as-saheehayn stressing the importance of prophets sword, spear, provision from war booty, fear.

Regarding forcing pagans to Islam, most of the scholars are divided, the likes of ibn kathir and bin baaz say they can be forced. We also have a narration where the prophet threatened a polytheist with sword and invited him to Islam.

> Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu `alayhi wasallam) catching the sword, asked him, “Who will protect you from me.” He said, “Please forgive me.” Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu` alayhi wasallam) said, “On condition you testify that there is none worthy of worship but Allah and that I am His Messenger.”

Reference : https://ilookilisten.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/who-do-you-trust-hadith-no-2553/

PS: I donot support ISIS or Al-Qaeda in any way. Sk. Fawzaan has already spoken against ISIS telling that they are doing  **Jihad in path of Satan** . You need more information of khawarij/kharijites.

PPS: OT and NT further strengthen Islam's call for offensive Jihad.

> OT : those who donot seek the Lord of Israel shall be put to death.
>
> NT : Jesus said I have not come to bring peace on earth but have come with a sword.

Comment: "No doubt Islam is a religion of Mercy and justice but Muslims are peaceful with those who are peaceful with them." The rest of your post contradicts this.

Comment: Edited first para

Comment: That still suggest a stance that contradicts the rest of the answer. Saying "no we're not gonna become Muslims" is peaceful.

Comment: That's the best I can do till more knowledge Dawn's upon me

Comment: You cannot cite one sentence of a  conference article  as a proof that Shia school of thought approve of conquest by jihad.