# Why are people in your coumminity commiting violent acts in the name of your God?

Tags: practical-islam

I don't care if the question is closed.. its an honest question from someone who knows next to nothing about your religion.  With so many different sources saying so many things, how can someone uninformed as I make a decision on weather a group of people want to kill me? It seems like people in your community are glorified for committing violence in the name of Allah.

Why wouldn't I be cautious of a group of Muslim men? When it is consistently this demographic that is involved in mass murder?

Which is why I came to the community to ask; why are people doing such horrible acts in the name of your God?

I don't mean to offend- I looked through other questions and answers and it seems like for the most part- those of you who adhere to your religion are modest and humble.. however I don't understand why 'radical' members feel they posses the right take lives.

Comment: This isn't true, in Islam killing one person the same thing as killing all the humanity, if you want I can give you arguments from Quran and Sunnah, and killing was only allowed in war ad people who kills in the name of Islam are using this fact in wrong position, these are minority that doesn't really represent Islam, and even in war prophet Muhammad peace be upon him has forbidden killing innocent people, women, old person and even animals and trees.

Comment: "how can someone uninformed as I make a decision on weather a group of people want to kill me" Listen to the group of people. The Pew polls give a good idea about what Muslims think and in what ways that mass of people fractionates along their commitment to doctrinal requirements or recommendations that are incompatible with human rights, or to propagating Islam violently. See also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33207/is-islam-really-a-religion-of-peace/38824#38824); expansionism has always been a reality in Islamic legal discourse and the politics of the Islamic empire.

Comment: @Uma "killing non-combatant civilians" As far as I'm aware, that's not something on which there is consensus. It certainly doesn't cover forbidding attacks that produce collateral damage, and o9.10 of the reliance of the traveler for example states "It is permissible to kill old men (0: old man (shaykh) meaning someone more than forty
years of age) and monks."